# Definition of Limit of a Function

Tags: limits, derivatives, definition

I'm a little confused by the definition of the limit of a function-on one hand I feel the definition suggests that your limiting variable is shrinking into a little delta ball- on the other hand when it comes to derivatives, of things like $x^2$ for $x \ge 0$ $-x^2$ for $x \le 0$ to show that it isn't second differentiable we consider$f(-h)$ and $f(h)$, where these h's somehow never take on a negative sign. Which is it, and what resolves my confusion?

Comment: To resolve your confusion, I suggest forgetting about words and descriptions such as the one you gave and use quantifiers instead.

Comment: Well, again, I feel like it ends up being the delta ball, so abs(h-0)< delta, but this doesn't seem to align with solutions to definition-of-derivative problems I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of $h$ take negative and positive signs. The problem is this:  The function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2&;x\geq0\\-x^2&;x\leq0\end{cases}$$ has a first derivative of $f'(x) = |x|$.

The reason that $f$ does not have a second derivative is that the functin $g(x)=|x|$ does not have a derivative at $0$, so let's just look at that.

$g$ has a derivative at $x=0$ if the limit $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(0+h)-g(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{|h|}{h}$$ exists, and here is where the problem is. The thing is that if $h>0$, then $\frac{|h|}{h} = 1$, and for $h<0$, $\frac{|h|}{h}=-1$.

Strictly speaking, for the limit to exist and be equal to $L$, this statement should be true:

$$\forall \epsilon>0\exists \delta > 0\forall h, |h|<\delta: \left|\frac{|h|}{h}-L\right|.$$

However, this statement is not true, because for every $\delta>0$, we can find values $h_1=\frac{\delta}{2}$ and $h_2=-\frac{\delta}{2}$ such that $\frac{|h_1|}{h_1}=1$ and $\frac{|h_2|}{h_2}=-1$.

---

I see you are asking about the formula for the second derivative which is $$\frac{f(x+h)+2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}.$$ 
However, this is not the definition of the second derivative. This is only a formula to calculate the derivative *if the derivative exists.* Therefore, it is useless in your case and tells you nothing. [This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative#Limit) in wikipedia tells you the same thing (emphasis added):

> Please note that the existence of the above limit **does not mean** that the function $f$ has a second derivative. The limit above just gives a possibility for calculating the second derivative but **does not provide a definition**.

Comment: I understand that the absolute value has no derivative, what I don't understand is why in evaluating the "formula" for second derivative. $(f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h))/h^2$ The +h term gets evaluated to the positive side and the -h gets evaluated to the negative side... Is this just because we know that *one* of them will be on one side or the other from symmetry?

Comment: For instance, on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative look under limit.

Comment: @Anthony I did just that, I edited my answer. Is it any clearer now?

Comment: I don't think so-I fully understand that there is not a second derivative, my confusion is how they actually used the definition of limit-how did they compute that limit? If h can be negative or positive, so can 0+h or 0-h...

Comment: Indeed, but $f(0+h)+f(x-h)$ in your case, when $x=0$, is $f(h)+f(-h)$. If $h>0$, that equals $h^2 + (-h^2) = 0$. If $h<0$, it equals $-(h^2) + h^2=0$, so it's the same.

Comment: But that is why. h does not have an inherent sign associated with it? It can be + or -! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, $h$ can be both negative and positive. If it was just positive, then you would not be talking about a limit, but a *right* limit.